# Возможно ли сделать такое?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

есть попап с режимом работы. К примеру на фотов видно что сегодня, работает с 10 00 до 22:00, и есть желтая полоска которая показывает прогресс дня, т.е если говорить что сейчас 14:00 т.е полоска находится по середине, если сейчас 11:00 то полоска у начало . Если да то каким образом можно сделать такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим ширина полоски - это 100%. В данном случае 100% это 20 - 10.

Осталось узнать процент заполнения.

```
var hFrom = 10,
    hTo = 22,
    hNow = 14,
    percent = 100 * (hNow - hFrom) / (hTo - hFrom);

$('.progress-line .fill').width(percent + '%');
```

```
<div class="progress-line">
  <div class="fill" style="width: 20%"></div>
</div>
```

```
.progress-line {
  height: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.progress-line .fill {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  background: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/qvw3rdyu/6/

Comment: Дело не в стилизации. Дело в том что бы узнать на текущий момент состояния в процентах. Ведь если сервис работает с 10 до 22. То если пользователь зайдет в 14 00 то у него полоса будет 50%, а если он зайдет часов в 19 то полоса будет 90%. В этом вопрос

Comment: Я написал как узнать процент

Comment: Спасибо, действительно сперва не заметил

Comment: Но каким образом можно получить переменную hnow

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa, предпочтительнее получить ее с сервера. Например прописать атрибутом в какой-нибудь тег и получить js'кой. Но можно и в js получить `var d = new Date();  var n = d.getHours();`